# Soundcloud JS Custom Player - How to split sets out into tracks for minimal skin?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to customise the sc-player-minimal.html example included with the JS custom player package.

It's defualt operation is that you have to add multiple soundcloud links to **single tracks** in the html, and when loaded a wav player is presented for each track.

What i'd like to be able to do is add just a link to a set rather than multiple tracks, and have the player split the tracks out from the set and then present all the tracks in the set with an individual wav player. Currently it just creates a tracklist with only one player.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no pre-packaged way to do this, but you could use the API to fetch the set information, then dynamically write links to each of the tracks into the page and then let the plugin do its thing.

Comment: I hadn't considered doing it this way round. I tried to split the set processing in the players javascript - but tbh my js is not that advanced! This method would keep me from butchering the players code :) Many thanks...